# Removing whitespace

Tags: php, string

I am writing html content to a BML file, how can I remove new lines/whitespace so it is all in one long string?

does `preg_replace("\n","")` work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easiest way to remove all whitespace from a code file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761662/easiest-way-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-a-code-file) and [a couple others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+whitespace+php "StackOverflow Search for remove+whitespace+php")

Comment: @Gordon if that upsets you, better don't google the question :)

Comment: Yeah, I know guys, my bad. I was going away to do something and I thought there may be an answer waiting for me. However,as the thread unfolds it turns out I need to keep my whitespaces between words.

Comment: @Hannes this one doesnt upset me. There is way worse. I mean sure, @Liam could have searched a bit before asking, but by now I already know people rarely (or only briefly) do that (it's tedious). But since I have been given the power to closevote, I just do what I think I am supposed to do with that power. So, no hard feelings anybody. It's nothing personal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better use platform independent ending line constant `PHP_EOL` which is equivalent to `array("\n", "\r", "\r\n")` in this case...

```
$html = str_replace(PHP_EOL, null, $html);
```

Comment: @Hannes For removing whitespace there is a `trim()` function in PHP.

Comment: @Otar trim only strips whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string ... otherwise str_replace wouldn't have been necessary in the first place :)

Comment: @Hannes What stand in front of using them both? :P

Comment: Well, he wants to remove all white spaces, even between chars, so after removing all linebreaks, and remaining white spaces at the begining and end of the string, the white spaces between, would still remain :P

Answer (score 2):

preg_match only compares and returns matches, it does not replace anything, you could use `$string = str_replace(array(" ","\n"),"",$string)`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove newline characters, `str_replace` is all you need:

```
$str = str_replace("\n", '', $str);
```

Comment: you forgot the whitespaces :)

Answer (score 0):

The `preg_match` method does not work in this case as it does *not replace* characters but tries to *find matches*.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace all \n with a space, then replace double spaces with a single space (being as HTML does not use more than one space by default)

```
$str = str_replace('\n', ' ', $str);
$str = str_replace('  ', ' ', $str);
```